# Splash page for social engine site

Tags: socialengine

How would i go about creating an splash page that would be the first page when someone goes to the site. The site is built on socialengine.

I guess it doesn't have to be html, could be php.

I have tried updating the htaccess file with DirectoryIndex index.html

Adding redirect code, (broke site)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out by another post, it wasn't for an html page but i modified it and works.

Your main .htaccess file

Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteRule (.*) main.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

FileETag Size